# Unable to play music on hold in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, ivr

In my dialplan music on hold was working earlier but its not working now.My musiconhold.conf

```
;
; Music on Hold -- Sample Configuration
;

    [old-default]
    mode=files
    directory=/var/lib/asterisk/mohmp3
    random=yes 

    [old-quiet]
    mode=files
    directory=/var/lib/asterisk/quiet-mp3

    #include musiconhold-vicidial.conf

    ; valid mode options:
    ; quietmp3      -- default
    ; mp3           -- loud
    ; mp3nb         -- unbuffered
    ; quietmp3nb    -- quiet unbuffered
    ; custom        -- run a custom application
    ; files         -- read files from a directory in any Asterisk supported format
```

my cli shows
**Music class default requested but no musiconhold loaded.**

the output of moh reload

```
localhost*CLI> moh reload
  == Parsing '/etc/asterisk/musiconhold.conf':   == Found
[Jul  4 11:23:08] WARNING[4504]: res_musiconhold.c:1068 moh_scan_files: Cannot open dir /var/lib/asterisk/mohmp3 or dir does not exist
[Jul  4 11:23:08] WARNING[4504]: res_musiconhold.c:1068 moh_scan_files: Cannot open dir /var/lib/asterisk/quiet-mp3 or dir does not exist
```

I dont know what hapened it was working fine earlier.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the contents of your musiconhold-vicidial.conf ?

It looks to me like that file is not being loaded at all;  try specifying the full path to the file on the include line.

Comment: there is no such file musiconhold-vicidial.conf in my asterisk folder,i dont why its including it.i tried removing it but that dint solve my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your warnings, It shows /var/lib/asterisk/mohmp3 does not exist.
You have to create your music on hold directory(i.e mohmp3,quiet-mp3) within /var/lib/asterisk/moh and then edit your musiconhold.conf ex:
    `[mohmp3]
mode=files
directory=/var/lib/asterisk/moh/mohmp3`

And atlast reload music on hold `asterisk -rx'moh reload'`.

If it is successfully then  `asterisk -rx'moh show classes'` will give you output of your created music on hold directory